# What should I do when I add too much salt to rice?

Tags: flavor, rice, salt

I accidentally added extra salt to my rice. Is there anything I can do now?

Comment: Before or after cooking? Will you be serving the rice alone or as a side dish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add extra rice to your salt.

Cook another batch of rice, with no salt, then mix both batches.

Alternatively, you could attempt to make a fried rice dish from it where you add no more salt but plenty of vegetables, nuts, fruit, meat....